# Distinct with a group by

Tags: mysql, distinct, distinct-values

I need to write a query that filter my data. 
In my table i have all the data grouped by val1 but multiple values of val2 witch i have to remove.

My table is something like this:

```
| id | val1 | val2 | other |
|------------------|-------
| 1  | A1   |  b1  | ...
| 2  | A1   |  b1  | ...
| 3  | A1   |  b2  |

| 4  | A2   |  b1  |

| 5  | A3   |  b1  |
| 6  | A3   |  b1  |
| 7  | A3   |  b2  |

| 8  | A4   |  b1  |
| 9  | A4   |  b3  |
| 10 | A5   |  b1  |
```

And i need this:

```
| id | val1 | val2 |
|------------------|
| 1  | A1   |  b1  |
| 3  | A1   |  b2  |
| 4  | A2   |  b1  |
| 5  | A3   |  b1  |
| 7  | A3   |  b2  |
| 8   ...
| 9   ...
| 10  ...
```

it's a sort of select *,distinct(val2) from table group by val1..

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track using a `GROUP BY`

Following should return the results as per your question

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, val1, val2
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY
       val1, val2
```

**Breakdown**

- Use an aggregate function on the column you don't wish to group on. In our example this is the `MIN` aggregate function on the `id` column. This returns the lowest id for each group
- `GROUP BY` all the columns you want to get a *distinct* value of